# DAYS datatype in mySql

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

i want to store a weekdays in my database like (Sunday ,...,Friday)
what datatype should i use? thank you :)

```
CREATE TABLE Operations(

   operation_id       int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY(operation_id),
   openingtime        time,
   closingTime        time,
   operationDay       ?????
   restaurant_id      int,
   FOREIGN KEY(restaurant_id)
   REFERENCES restaurant(restaurant_id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

example

id  = 1
openingtime = 7:00am
closingTime = 10:00pm
operationDay = monday
restaurant_id = 2
```

the purpose of storing days and time, i want to display if the restaurant is open or close real-time.

Comment: There are 7 days, why not int 1-7?

Answer (score 3):

How about a column with the `ENUM` type? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

From the documentation:

> An ENUM is a string object with a value chosen from a list of
>   permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column
>   specification at table creation time. It has these advantages:
>
> - Compact data storage in situations where a column has a limited set of
>     possible values. The strings you specify as input values are
>     automatically encoded as numbers. See Section 12.8, “Data Type Storage
>     Requirements” for the storage requirements for ENUM types.
> - Readable queries and output. The numbers are translated back to the
>     corresponding strings in query results.

So your table definition would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Operations(
    ...
    operationDay       ENUM('monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'),
    ...
);
```

Comment: Yes agree, Enum would be a good choice though considering that data is static.